# Moving reset password to backend, Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have user authorization on backend only (for admins) and I am trying to move password reset function to backend.

**\backend\views\site\login.php**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>

            //fields for username and password

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

        <div style="color:#999;margin:1em 0">
               If you forgot your password you can <?= Html::a('reset it', ['request-password-reset']) ?>.
           </div>
```

**\backend\controllers\SiteController.php**

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
       //enters here instead
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
    {
       //not entering here
        $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm(); //placed in \common\models
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset password for email provided.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

The problem is when I click `reset it` the site redirects me to `login.php` again, so `actionRequestPasswordReset()` is not fired. Im new to Yii and would appreciate any help.

Comment: By default backend SiteController have `AccessControl`  filter which means if you are not logged in .. page will redirect you to login action

Comment: Thank you, I use another controller and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your controller's [Access Control Filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#access-control-filter) to permit users who haven't logged in to access `requestPasswordReset`:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['request-password-reset'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the array item in actions should be 'request-password-reset'

Comment: I've corrected the answer. For future reference you can just correct other peoples posts by editing them.